# Problemas en el main de un juego debido a la implemetacion

Tags: c++

Estoy realizando un juego estilo space invaders y necesito separar las clases y el main en distintos archivos. Al hacer esto tengo errores para implemetar todo. Cuando hice todo de corrido obtuve el resultado esperado pero separandolos el main no corre por que menciona que 3 funciones no existen gotoxy,ocultar cursos y pinta limites. Radica el problema en que no reconoce esas funciones y dicen que no han sido declaradas

Interfaz.h

```
#ifndef INTER_H
#define INTER_H


class Inter
{
public:
    void OcultarCursor();
    void gotoxy(int x, int y);
    void pintar_limites();
};

#endif // INTER_H
```

Interfaz.cpp

```
#include "inter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> // mas facilidad para los inputs y outputs con referencia a los caracteres especiales (ASCII)
#include <windows.h> // Biblioteca especial para sistemas operativos windows con funciones "especiales" para windows
#include<conio.h>// detectar si se han presionado ciertas teclas
#include<stdlib.h>
#define ARRIBA 72
#define IZQUIERDA 75
#define DERECHA 77
#define ABAJO 80
#include<list>
//Se define un numero para cada palabra por el codigo ASCII

void gotoxy( int x, int y)
{ //compilador de borland


    HANDLE hCon; // nombre del indentificador NOTA: CAMBIENLE EL NOMBRE EN EL FINAL
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // recuperar el identificador de la consola que aparece al correr el programa Parametro: tipo de control que deseamos tener de la consola (en este caso tomar el coontrol de la salida de la consola - Caracter de sallida debido a la accion de dar posicion a un caracter en pantalla Visualiza)
    COORD dwPos; // objeto de la biblioteca windows.h
    dwPos.X = x; // Posicion en X
    dwPos.Y = y; // Posicion en y
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCon, dwPos); //funcion de windows.h permite dar una posicion al cursor e imprimir en las cordenadas dispone 2 identificadores 1. Handle: nombre que le da el sistema a la ventana. 1er parametro Identificador de la consola 2do Parametro: Estructura de datos solo recibe objetos de coord (windows.h) (sistema de cordenadas x/y)
}

void OcultarCursor() //Funcion para ocultar cursor
{
    HANDLE hCon;
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO tam;//Controla la apariencia del cursor
    tam.dwSize= 2; //Tamano del cursor en pantalla
    tam.bVisible= FALSE; //EL cursor NO se mostrara en pantalla

    SetConsoleCursorInfo(hCon,&tam); //Paso por referencia para acceder a los datos y modificarlos
}


void pintar_limites()
{
    for (int i=2; i<78; i++)
    {   //Margen horizontal
        gotoxy(i,3); printf("%c",205); //Margen de la parte superior con el simbolo #205 del codigo ASCII
        gotoxy(i,33); printf("%c",205);
    }

    for(int i=4; i<33; i++)
    {   //Margen vertical
        gotoxy(2, i); printf("%c",186);
        gotoxy(77, i); printf("%c",186);
    }

    //Esquinas del margen
    gotoxy(2,3 ); printf("%c",201);
    gotoxy(2,33); printf("%c",200);
    gotoxy(77,3); printf("%c",187);
    gotoxy(77,33); printf("%c",188);

}
```

Nave.h

```
#ifndef NAVE_H
#define NAVE_H
#include "inter.h"

class NAVE: public Inter
{
    int x; //Datos miembro
    int y;
    int corazones;
    int vidas;

public:
   NAVE(int _x, int _y, int _corazones, int _vidas): x(_x), y(_y), corazones(_corazones), vidas(_vidas){} //Constructor parametrizado inicializando variables
   int X(){return x;}
   int Y() {return y;}
   int VID() {return vidas;}
   void COR() {corazones--;}
   void pintar (); //pintar la nave
   void borrar (); //Borrar rastro de la nave
   void mover(); //mover la nave desde teclado
   void pintar_corazones(); //barra de salud
   void morir();
};

#endif // NAVE_H
```

Nave.cpp

```
#include "nave.h"
#include "inter.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> // mas facilidad para los inputs y outputs con referencia a los caracteres especiales (ASCII)
#include <windows.h> // Biblioteca especial para sistemas operativos windows con funciones "especiales" para windows
#include<conio.h>// detectar si se han presionado ciertas teclas
#include<stdlib.h>
#define ARRIBA 72
#define IZQUIERDA 75
#define DERECHA 77
#define ABAJO 80
#include<list>
//Se define un numero para cada palabra por el codigo ASCII



void NAVE::pintar(){
     gotoxy(x,y);
     printf("  %c", 30); //Imprime el caracter 30 del codigo ASCII
     gotoxy(x,y+1); //Una posicion mas abajo
     printf(" %c%c%c", 40, 207,41);
     gotoxy(x,y+2);
     printf("%c%c %c%c", 30, 190, 190,30);
 }


void NAVE::borrar()
{
    gotoxy(x,y);
    printf("        "); //Borrar los rastros dela nave
    gotoxy(x,y+1);
    printf("        "); //Borrar los rastros dela nave
    gotoxy(x,y+2);
    printf("        "); //Borrar los rastros dela nave
}

void NAVE::mover()
{
   if(kbhit()) //hbhit= detecta si se ha presionado una tecla
   {
   char tecla=getch(); //getch= guarda la letra que se presiona a la variable tecla

   borrar(); //borrar rastros
   if (tecla== IZQUIERDA && x>3) x--; //evaluando que tecla se presiona y cambiando posicion de la nave hacia la izquierda
   if(tecla== DERECHA && x+6<77) x++; //cambiando posicion de la nave a la derecha, con margen
   //NOTA: Eje y esta invertido
   if(tecla== ARRIBA && y>4) y--; //moviendo la nave hacia arriba
   if(tecla== ABAJO && y+3<33) y++; //moviendo la nave hacia abajo
   if(tecla=='e') corazones--; //Decrese la cantidad de vidas al presionar la tecla 'e'
   pintar(); //Pintar rastros
   pintar_corazones();
   }
}


void NAVE::pintar_corazones()
{ //Posicion donde se emuestran las vidas

   gotoxy(50,2); printf("Vidas: %d",vidas);
   gotoxy(64,2);
   printf("Salud:");
   gotoxy (70,2);
   printf("        ");
 //Muestre corazones cuando la nave se mueva
   for(int i=0; i<corazones; i++)
   {
       gotoxy(70+i,2);
       printf("%c",3);
   }
}


void NAVE::morir()
{
    if(corazones==0)
    {    //Animacion para la explosion del la nave
        borrar();
        gotoxy(x,y);   printf("   **   ");
        gotoxy(x,y+1); printf("  **  ");
        gotoxy(x,y+2); printf("   **   ");

        Sleep(200);

        borrar();
        gotoxy(x,y);   printf(" * **  * ");
        gotoxy(x,y+1); printf("  **  ");
        gotoxy(x,y+2); printf(" *  ** *");
        Sleep(200);
        borrar();

        vidas--;
        corazones =3;
        pintar_corazones();
        pintar();

    }
}
```

Asteriscos. h

```
#ifndef AST_H
#define AST_H
#include "nave.h"
#include "inter.h"


class AST : public Inter
{
private:
    int x,y;
 public:
    AST(int _x, int _y): x(_x),y(_y){}

    void pintar();
    void mover();
    void choque(class NAVE &N); //Llamar a los metodos de la clase nave por referencias

    int X() {return x;}
    int Y() {return y;}
};

#endif // AST_H
```

astericos. cpp

```
#include "ast.h"
#include "inter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> // mas facilidad para los inputs y outputs con referencia a los caracteres especiales (ASCII)
#include <windows.h> // Biblioteca especial para sistemas operativos windows con funciones "especiales" para windows
#include<conio.h>// detectar si se han presionado ciertas teclas
#include<stdlib.h>
#define ARRIBA 72
#define IZQUIERDA 75
#define DERECHA 77
#define ABAJO 80
#include<list>
//Se define un numero para cada palabra por el codigo ASCII



void AST::pintar()
{  //Pintar los asteroides
    gotoxy(x,y);
    printf("%c",167);
}


void AST::mover(){
    gotoxy(x,y); printf(" "); //Borrar los rastros de los asteroides
    y++; //Movimiento de caida del asteroide
    if(y>32)
    {
        x=rand()%71+4; //Numero entre 2 y 77 para que aparezca el esteroide al azar
        y=4;
    }
   pintar(); //Pintar la nave
}

void AST::choque(class NAVE &N)
{
    if(x>=N.X() && x<N.X()+6 && y>=N.Y() && y<N.Y()+2) //Intervalo que ocupa la nave para moverse
    {
        N.COR(); //Restar los corazones cuando haya colision
        N.borrar();
        N.pintar();
        N.pintar_corazones();
        x=rand()%71+4; //Numero entre 2 y 77 para que aparezca el esteroide al azar
        y=4;
    }
}
```

bala . h

```
#ifndef BALA_H
#define BALA_H
#include "nave.h"
#include "inter.h"

class BALA : public Inter
{

 private:
     int x,y;
 public:
     BALA(int _x, int _y): x(_x),y(_y){};
     int X() {return x;}
     int Y() {return y;}
     void mover();
     bool fuera();

};


#endif // BALA_H
```

bala.cpp

```
#include "bala.h"
#include "inter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> // mas facilidad para los inputs y outputs con referencia a los caracteres especiales (ASCII)
#include <windows.h> // Biblioteca especial para sistemas operativos windows con funciones "especiales" para windows
#include<conio.h>// detectar si se han presionado ciertas teclas
#include<stdlib.h>
#define ARRIBA 72
#define IZQUIERDA 75
#define DERECHA 77
#define ABAJO 80
#include<list>
//Se define un numero para cada palabra por el codigo ASCII

using namespace std;
void BALA::mover()
{
    gotoxy(x,y); printf(" ");

    if(y>4) y--; //movimiento de la bala hacia arriba
    gotoxy(x,y); printf("*");
}

bool BALA::fuera()
{
   if(y==4) return true;
   return false;

}
```

Main . cpp en este no reconoce las funciones gotoxy, Ocultar Cursor y Pintar_limites

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> // mas facilidad para los inputs y outputs con referencia a los caracteres especiales (ASCII)
#include <windows.h> // Biblioteca especial para sistemas operativos windows con funciones "especiales" para windows
#include <conio.h>// detectar si se han presionado ciertas teclas
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRIBA 72
#define IZQUIERDA 75
#define DERECHA 77
#define ABAJO 80
#include "inter.h"
#include "bala.h"
#include "ast.h"
#include "nave.h"
#include <list>//Se define un numero para cada palabra por el codigo ASCII

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    OcultarCursor();
    pintar_limites();

    NAVE N(37,30,3,3); //Poisicion de la nave y vida
    N.pintar();
    N.pintar_corazones();

   list<AST*>A;
   list<AST*>::iterator itA;
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ //Crear 5 asteroides
        A.push_back((new AST(rand()%75+3, rand()&5+4)));
   }

    list<BALA*>B; //Lista de punteros
    list<BALA*>::iterator it; //iteraror para operar los elementos de la lista




    bool game_over= false; // Cuando se corre el progama, game_over es falso
    int puntos=0; //Variable para almacenar los puntos obtenidos

    while(!game_over) //se ejecuta el while cuando la variable game over es falsa
    {
        gotoxy(4,2);
        printf("Puntos: %d", puntos);
       if(kbhit())
       {
           char tecla= getch();
           if (tecla== 'a')
              B.push_back(new BALA(N.X()+2, N.Y()-1)); //Crea la salida de la bala a partir de las corrdenadas de la nave
       }

       for(it= B.begin(); it != B.end(); it++){

           (*it) -> mover(); //Mover las balas a traves de la lista por punteros

           if((*it)->fuera())
           {
               gotoxy((*it)->X(), (*it)->Y());
               printf(" ");
               delete(*it); //Eliminar elemento de la lista cuando salga de rango
               it= B.erase(it); //Volver a enlazar iteradores en la lista
           }
       }

      for(itA= A.begin(); itA!= A.end(); itA++)
      {
          (*itA)->mover();
          (*itA)->choque(N);

      }

      for(itA= A.begin(); itA != A.end(); itA++) //itA controla asteroides
      {
          for(it= B.begin(); it != B.end(); it++){//it controla las balas
              //Borramos la bala cuando colisiona
              if((*itA) ->X()== (*it)->X() && ((*itA)->Y()+1== (*it)->Y() || (*itA)->Y()== (*it)->Y() )){
                  gotoxy((*it)->X(), (*it)->Y());
                  printf(" ");

                  delete(*it);
                  it= B.erase(it);

                  //Borrar asteroide que colisiona
                  A.push_back(new AST(rand()%74+3,4));
                  gotoxy((*itA)->X(), (*itA)->Y());
                  printf(" ");
                  delete(*itA);
                  itA= A.erase(itA);

                  puntos+=5; //5 puntos cada que detecte una colision
              }
          }

      }

      if(N.VID()==0) game_over= true;
       N.morir();
       N.mover();
       Sleep(30); //Detener la ejecucion del progama por 30 milisegundos
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo no estás haciendo lo que realmente quieres.

Siento que todavía no dominas bien las clases y quieres aplicar todo lo que has aprendido.

Te diré algo:

> No es necesario convertir todo en clases, ni usar la herencia de forma rebuscada.

---

Olvídate de las clases en los archivos de la interfaz. Usa funciones a secas modificando `interfaz.h` así:

```
#ifndef INTER_H
#define INTER_H

void OcultarCursor();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void pintar_limites();

#endif // INTER_H
```

Y en el archivo `interfaz.cpp` escribe bien el nombre del archivo:

```
#include "interfaz.h"
```

Con esto tienes que dejar de heredar `Asteriscos`, `Bala` y otros de la clase `Inter`, porque no existe más.

Naves.h:

```
#ifndef NAVE_H
#define NAVE_H

class NAVE
{
    ...
};
```

Asteriscos.h:

```
#ifndef AST_H
#define AST_H
#include "nave.h"

class AST
{
    ...
};

#endif // AST_H
```

---

Adicionalmente puedes eliminar algunas directivas de preprocesador que no estás usando y así simplificar el código. O también hacer uso de funciones de STL de C++ como `std::cout` en `iostream` en lugar de `printf` en `stdio.h`.